# how to make nose show logging *before* dropping into pdb?

Tags: python, unit-testing, automated-tests, nose, pdb

wondering if anyone knows the dark incantations necessary to get nose to print the log output *before* the pdb console comes up on a failure, so I can see what's happened up the breakpoint/exception. The below shows logging on failure, and drops into pdb, but the logging only goes to the screen after I continue out of pdb. grr!

$ nosetests -s -v --pdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default nose captures both stdout and logging output. But you can disable capturing. For stdout (print statements) it is done with `-s` or `--nocapture` ([docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/capture.html#cmdoption-s)) command line option and for python `logging` it is done with `--nologcapture` ([docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/logcapture.html#cmdoption--nologcapture)). So

```
$> nosetests -s --nologcapture
```

should do it.